# MMenu plugin don't opens to right in Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, mobile, mmenu

After searching the web I found that the best menu for mobile is the mmenu.frebsite.nl.
The mmenu has "Advanced" option to open the menu on the left or right, and it does working in desktop version, but when checked on mobile (iphone and android), both buttons open the menu on the left side.
Anyone tried the options on mobile or knows how to fix it?... Thanks.

Comment: You should probably post your code.  Your problem is either that this just isn't supported on the mobile device or that there is some error in your code.  You should be able to ascertain what it is expected to do from documentation but to figure out if there is a problem in your code, you need to post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the menu to open to the right involves two steps, the first isn't explained very well within mmenu's documentation. Note: I'm using version 4.2 at the time of this response.

Step 1)

Include the positioning CSS **or** SASS file in your project (*extensions/jquery.mmenu.positioning.scss* **or** *extensions/jquery.mmenu.positioning.css*). Including these files also allows you to set the zposition value.

Step 2)

Set the right value in the mmenu function

```
$(function() {
  $('nav#main-nav').mmenu({
  classes: 'mm-dark',
  position: 'right',
  zposition: 'front'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using position: 'right' is depreciated.
So try

```
 $('nav#main-nav').mmenu({
   classes: "mm-dark",
   offCanvas: { position  : "right", zposition: "front" }
  });
```